# Django coverage testing login and logout views is not working

Tags: python, django, code-coverage, test-coverage

I got this login and logout views on my views.py :

```
class Login(View):
    template_name = ['cost_control_app/login.html', 'cost_control_app/home.html']

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UsersForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name[0],{"form":form,})


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            form_group = GroupsForm()
            lista = definetree(request.user.groups.all()[0].name, request.user.id)
            return render_to_response(self.template_name[1], {"form_group" : form_group,
                                                           "groups":lista[0],
                                                           "subgroups":lista[1] ,
                                                           "sub_subgroups":lista[2],
                                                           "cost_items":lista[3],
                                                           "count_requests":lista[4],
                                                            },RequestContext(request))
        else:
            #messages.error(request, "Usuario o password incorrecto")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cost_control_app:login'))


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request) 
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cost_control_app:login'))
```

And im using coverage to make unitary test on them, this is my authentication_test.py :

```
from django.test import TestCase
from cost_control_app.models import *
from cost_control_app.form import *
from cost_control_app.views.views_authentication import *
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.importlib import import_module


class test_login(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['test_data_cost_control_app.json']

    def test_login_get(self):
        request = HttpRequest()
        request.method = 'GET'
        Login.as_view()(request)

    def test_login_post(self):
        request = HttpRequest()
        request.method = 'POST'
        request.POST['username'] = "jsanchezs"
        request.POST['password'] = "pbkdf2_sha256$20000$PFQCunwR7Rzz$rhTeSCRUCz8hqwYGf8Uprj+B/5yAmYMzjc6jamY9eCw="
        Login.as_view()(request)
```

Thing is, test_login doesn't work when user authenticates and i dont know why (user gets None), user and password are correct and they do login inside my app, but not in this test...also, i don't know how to test the logout view.

Users are created in a json fixtures data :

```
[
    {"pk":1,
    "model":"auth.user",
    "fields":{
                "password":,
                "last_login":"2015-12-30 14:17:39.413827",
                "is_superuser":1,
                "username":"jsanchezs",
                "first_name":"Juan David",
                "last_name":"Sanchez",
                "email":"anything@gmail.com",
                "is_staff":1,
                "is_active":1,
                "date_joined":"2015-12-30 14:17:29.150420"
             }

    }
]
```

Any help ?, thanks in advance.

Comment: is it the hash value of password? you should provide it as plain text if yes

Comment: It is indeed, i already tried that too but same result =(

Comment: I think it is better to use client to send your requests, check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/

Comment: @AhmedHosny thanks, gonna check it right now !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to try the client as follows,

```
from django.test import Client
class test_login(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['test_data_cost_control_app.json']

    def test_login_post(self):
        c = Client()
        response = c.post('url to login', {'username': 'jsanchezs', 'password': 'password in plain text'}) # you can use here reverse for urls
        self.assertEqual(response.status, 200) # or any other value
```

It is a prototype, I'm just explaining the idea. Check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/

You can check if the user has successfully logged in by `self.assertIn('_auth_user_id', c.session)` or specific user by `self.assertEqual(int(c.session['_auth_user_id']), user.pk)`

In `setUp` method you should create the user in the first place as the unittests create its own db.

**Update**
This is an update to show how to create a user and test login, authenticate

```
class test_login(TestCase):
        fixtures = ['test_data_cost_control_app.json']
        def setUp(self):
            self.user = User.objects.create_user(
        username='jsanchezs', email='jacob@test.com', password='password in plain text')
        def test_login_post_success(self):
            c = Client()
            response = c.post('url to login', {'username': self.user.username, 'password': 'password in plain text'}) # you can use here reverse for urls
            self.assertEqual(response.status, 200) # or any other value
        def test_authenticate_success(self):
            result = authenticate(username=self.user.username, password='password in plain text')
            self.assertTrue(result is not None)
```

Comment: It's cool, but how do i test the user authentication line i have in my view in order to return user not none ? may i replace response for user = c.post ?

Comment: i apreciate a lot your help, and im sorry for bother you with so many questions, as you see, i need to test my view, and there i have this line : user=authenticate(username = username, password = password)...as i need to test that specifically, i can't replace it as i understand, am i wrong ?

Comment: I mean, how to test that function specifically, not replacing it

Comment: I think the issue is in the hashed password generation, and that's why authenticate function returns none...

Comment: You have to create the user first, `authenticate` returns None because there is no User there in test db. I'll update my answer to elaborate more about this.

Comment: No, i did create users in a json fixtures data, from there im taking the user and password but its not one hashed by the framework, it's one i put simply there....the issue is exactly that, i need a valid password in the fixtures that i can call in authenticate function but dont know how to create it there...i updated my questions adding the fixture so you can see please.

Comment: check update. I did not get your point. To be sure that the user has been created inside the tests, please `self.assertEqual(User.objects.count(), 1)`. To get the hased value of password, you can after creating the user object, invoke `user.password`

Comment: Your code creates the user, and hashess the password correctly ( what i needed before ), but the weird part is that authenticate function keeps returning none =( ...it's doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Could you please add your current code and update the question with the comment on the line that you thinks that It does not work

Comment: Guess i have to reinstall my apps because after a few tries it worked, thanks a lot Ahmed !! now i have to look how to test the logout view.